# Search the entire text of an `object` field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index which has an `object` property which stores some very dynamic JSON. I'd like to do full-text search on that JSON field. How do I index this field so that I can see if a certain word appears anywhere in the JSON, without knowing the exact key it will appear in, in advance? Like, is there a way to just index all leaf nodes of the JSON property? I'm on ElasticSearch 6.8 by the way, so I don't have the [`flattened` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/flattened.html), which I think does this.

Index definition

```
PUT /test?include_type_name=true
{
  "settings": {"number_of_shards": 1, "number_of_replicas": 1},
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "_source": {"enabled": "true"},
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "object",
          "enabled": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document insertion

```
PUT /test/_doc/1
{
  "content": {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "text": "42"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "42"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder added some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the `flattened` field type is what you need. But until your upgrade, you can do it using [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-mapping-type). In the mapping below, we match any string field inside the `content` object field to `text` and we also copy its value into another field called `content_text` that we're going to be able to search on:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "full_name": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "path_match": "content.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "content_text"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "content_text": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "object",
        "enabled": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your sample document:

```
PUT /test/_doc/1
{
  "content": {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "text": "42"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now you can search on that new field as if you were searching on any field inside the `content` field:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content_text": "42"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks great. Will test it out tomorrow. Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome, let me know!

Comment: I get this error when creating the index:
```
# PUT /test
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "class_cast_exception",
        "reason": "class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
      }
    ],
    "type": "class_cast_exception",
    "reason": "class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess I need to test this on 6.8, then. Stay tuned...

Comment: Got it to work just by adding ?include_type_name=true

Comment: Happy to ask as a separate question, but any idea how I could modify this query to look for a bigram? E.g. the keywords "acme" "corp" appearing one after another?

Comment: @michaelsnowden Indeed, I suggest to ask a new question since it's a new requirement, thank you

Comment: I have a follow-up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214765/cant-see-dynamic-template-field-value-in-elasticsearch